# flutter check connection speed download and upload

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Try to display the download and upload speed on the screen with a button
I searched a lot on the internet for a package or an explanation for this, but I couldn't find it
[image]

Comment: Try using this package - internet_speed_test: https://pub.dev/packages/internet_speed_test